# Why am I getting an Unresolved External Symbol error while the typedef is present?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a converter for quaternions to euler angles, I have written this code:

```
//(...)
/*
* Converter Includes
*/
#include "EulerAngles.h"
//(...)
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL n_QuatToEuler( AMX* amx, cell* params )
{
    Quat q;
    q.x = amx_ctof(params[1]);
    q.y = amx_ctof(params[2]);
    q.z = amx_ctof(params[3]);
    q.w = amx_ctof(params[4]);
    EulerAngles EU = Eul_FromQuat(q,params[5]);
    //(...)
    return 1;
}
//(...)
```

I included the EulerAngles.c from http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/euler_angle/ into my project, I also downloaded all the other files into my project.

When I try to compile my project I get these error messages from Visual Studio 2012:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct Quat __cdecl Eul_FromQuat(struct Quat,int)" (?Eul_FromQuat@@YA?AUQuat@@U1@H@Z)    .\calculatorSAMP\calculatorSAMP.obj calculatorSAMP
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   .\calculatorSAMP\Release\calculatorSAMP.dll calculatorSAMP
```

the QuadTypes.h which is included in EulerAngles.h has this code:

```
/**** QuatTypes.h - Basic type declarations ****/
#ifndef _H_QuatTypes
#define _H_QuatTypes
/*** Definitions ***/
typedef struct {float x, y, z, w;} Quat; /* Quaternion */
enum QuatPart {X, Y, Z, W};
typedef float HMatrix[4][4]; /* Right-handed, for column vectors */
typedef Quat EulerAngles;    /* (x,y,z)=ang 1,2,3, w=order code  */
#endif
```

What am I missing here?

I tried to edit it to:

```
/**** QuatTypes.h - Basic type declarations ****/
#ifndef _H_QuatTypes
#define _H_QuatTypes
/*** Definitions ***/
struct Quat {float x, y, z, w;}; /* Quaternion */
enum QuatPart {X, Y, Z, W};
typedef float HMatrix[4][4]; /* Right-handed, for column vectors */
#define EulerAngles Quat ;    /* (x,y,z)=ang 1,2,3, w=order code  */
#endif
```

But it caused more errors.

Comment: It looks like it's not linking in `EulerAngles.c`. How are you compiling?

Comment: "Build Project" from the BUILD menu in VS2012, I qadded EurlerAngles.c to the files in the project.

Comment: I included the source code of EulerAngles.c into my main .cpp file and it does compile, so why isn't my file linked?

Comment: `Eul_FromQuat@@YA?AUQuat@@U1@H@Z` looks like it is expecting a C++ symbol. Are you compiling the source as C or C++?

Comment: compiling as C++ . I have a .C file in the solutionexplorer.

Comment: Maybe I did include the .c file wrong in the solution explorer? I did right click projectname > Add > existing item > selected EulerAngles.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is  a .c file, it is compiled as C by default.

You either have to change the "compile as" option for that file, or add `extern "C"` to the declaration in the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are missing a function:

```
Eul_FromQuat(struct Quat,int);
```

I don't see that function in the code you supplied.

So both your compiler and I conclude that it is missing, and is an unresolved symbol.

Comment: It is in http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/euler_angle/EulerAngles.c, which they say they added.